# VBA: assign string character by character

Tags: string, vba, ms-access

Most people ask how to get the characters from a string, which can be done by Mid().  I am trying to assign a string character by character in VBA code. The characters to be assigned depend on some calculated results.

I do not want to use string concatenation to form the string.

I have searched the web, but the posted solution, strName.Chars(i) (e.g., at MS development network), is not recognized in my 2007 Access VBA. 
Thanks

Comment: A sample input and expected output would be useful

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Mid` to set values, too.

```
Sub showMidExample()

    Dim s As String
    s = "aaaaa"

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        Mid(s, i) = "n"
        Debug.Print s

    Next i

End Sub
```

This prints out

```
naaaa
nnaaa
nnnaa
nnnna
nnnnn
```

Which is what you are looking for.

Comment: in Access 2010, Mid(s,i) = "n" caused an error: invalid procedure call or argument

Answer (score 0):

Since no working answer is posted. I assume that cannot be done in VBA and I have to use concatenation to form the string although that is cumbersome in my case.